# Use WebRTC on Android Studio using Java

Tags: java, android-studio, webrtc

I want make RTC application. I have searched on Google, but found not enough with Java.. I want to use WebRTC for it. How to use WebRTC on Android Studio. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

You can find some sample apps, such as https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC, https://medium.com/@SergioPaniego/tutorial-on-how-to-make-the-simplest-webrtc-android-app-daacb5c8d133, and more. They all use prebuilt versions of the library. As of today, you cannot use Android Studio to develop or build WebRTC, see [this open issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=9282).